# How to write inline ng-style for multiple conditions

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I'm trying to write an inline ng-style for multiple conditions in this format;

`<div ng-style="thisCondition && {'background-color':'black'},thisCondition2 && {'color':'green'}">`

but this code doesn't do anything, please is there any way I can check for multiple conditions in an inline ng-style?

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your style in css class and use `ng-class` :

```
ng-class="{myClass_1: myVar == true, myClass_2: myVar != true...}"
```